# Loop Through a Random List Generator

Tags: python, list, loops, random

This code I'm using is part of something bigger on I'm writing. In this part I create a random list of smaller size from a source list. Is there a way to loop over this random list creator x times and then save the new lists (e.g. `list1`, `list2`, `list3`, ..., `listx`)?

The code I'm using is this one:

```
positive_classifier = [
    positive[i] for i in sorted(
        random.sample(xrange(len(positive)), n_prot_classifier)) ]
```

Here `positive` is the source list I'm accessing and `n_prot_classifier` is a variable that I defined earlier that holds the length of the new list.

Comment: Of course you can run this inside a for-loop to do it multiple times.  I don't quite understand at what point you are having trouble.  Can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of lists by extending your code a bit. This will create a list containing `list_count` lists, each containing random elements from `positive`.

```
list_count = 5
positive_classifier = [
    [positive[i] for i in sorted(random.sample(xrange(len(positive)), n_prot_classifier))] 
    for _ in range(list_count)
]
```

Be aware the `positive_classifier` now is a list of lists, not a simple list as before.